# Api google maps v3 my own destination

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I discovered the option Supported Place Types in google maps api and I have a doubt , I understand the following code , but now I am interesting to show my own places with my own latitude and longitude options.

```
var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
  };
```

How I make my list , it's any possibilities to do this ?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your places in your own js array, and iterate over it retrieving its location, name and icon (for example) drawing a marker for each one.

You don't need to use Google Maps wrapper for Google Places ([google.maps.places.PlacesService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlacesService)) to draw your own markers. Just instantiate them using the [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker) object.